# How does Grover use styrofoam hoof covering?

Tags: percy-jackson

In the Percy Jackson series, Grover the satyr, is said to be using Styrofoam covering on his hoofs to blend with humans. But scientists have found that a kind of worms called "mealworms" or (Tenebrio molitor) are able to consume Styrofoam. So how is he able to use Styrofoam considering he spends a lot of time out there in Nature?

Comment: Grover used to wear styrofoam shaped fake feet and shoes over his hooves(does he wear socks? I dunno never mentioned in the book) to disguise as human. However why think about science when this book has already crossed into fantasy, not science? I think the author would not have considered the discovery of "meal worms".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grover wears Styrofoam foot shapes over his feet, and then *shoes and socks over them*. His feet don't get eaten by worms for the same reason that you don't get hangworms - shoes and socks.

> "I'm sorry," Grover sniffled "I'm a failure. I'm—I'm the worst satyr in the world."
>   He moaned, stomping his foot so hard it came off. I mean, the Converse hi-top came off. The inside was filled with Styrofoam, except for a hoof-shaped hole.
>   "Oh, Styx!" he mumbled.
>   <sub>*Percy Jackson & the Olympians*, book 1: *The Lighting Thief*, chapter 5: "I Play Pinochle With A Horse"</sub>

Also, Grover only wears his feet when he's trying to fit in with humans. If he's on his own, or with demigods, he uses his hooves without covering them.